# Is there an alternative way to open a huge SQL file rather than MySQL cmd , Em Editor and bigdump?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having lots of troubles while opening an SQL script. It's a database, because I managed to see a little bit of it before the things I tried crash down.

This is the script file that I get : https://steam.internet.byu.edu/
It's quite a popular database.

The zipped file is 17 GB and unzipped version of it is around 168 GB. I need to get the "steamid"s from "Player_Summaries" table. All I need is that column.  I've tried the following things so far:

-I read a lot of 'opening a huge sql file posts' here and tried to source and open the file via MySQL command line client. It ran almost all night but eventually it crashed.

-I tried Em Editor, I installed the latest version and that also crashed after opening 6-7% of the file. It gives "unexpected crash" and different error reasons every time I tried.

I mean I am not even trying to run/execute the file, I was just going to copy the lines I need and thats all. All help/advice is appreciated.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you tried Glogg (http://glogg.bonnefon.org/) ?

Comment: I'll try, thanks a lot !